# how to copy photos in ipad to my pc?

Tags: windows, ipad, itunes

i used the iTune to sync my photos to my ipad. but now, i lost the copies of the photos on my pc, so i want to restore them back from my ipad. but from the storage folder that ipad exposed, i cannot find my photos. and i am not sure if the photo sync function in iTune can sync the photos on my ipad to my pc, because it seems it can only sync stuffs from pc to ipad.

i am not sure if jail break the ipad can help me.

Comment: Use Dropbox to move them.

Comment: sorry man...dropbox is not available in china

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sync the iPad in iTunes there should be a tab for photo sync. It should allow you to sync the photos on the device to an application or folder on the PC.

If it is only a small number of photos, you could email them but it may reduce the quality of the images.

Comment: You could also try using a tool like this: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/mount-iphone-as-local-drive-to-get-root-access-in-my-computer/

Comment: yes, this tool works. unfortunately, the photo's meta information are changed my ipad...making it hard for me to organize my photos.